# Something adds routes with metric being consecutive integers starting from 201

Tags: netplan, ip, routing

My home router is connected to the WLAN with enp2s0 and to the internal LAN with enp3s0 (192.168.10.0/24). After migration from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 (done last week) something keeps adding and removing routes to my route table. In particular, the especially damaging is when the route to the 192.168.10.0/24 network gets removed...

What's funny, is that the route to the 192.168.10.0/24 keeps appearing and disappearing, as if there was some sort of racing condition.

Here's my route table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 enp2s0
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.2    0.0.0.0         UG    204    0        0 br0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    205    0        0 br1
10.0.3.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxcbr0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     203    0        0 enp3s0
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     207    0        0 vpn_dom
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     211    0        0 veth656d4511
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     213    0        0 veth9cad73ba
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     215    0        0 veth6a01cdf0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     217    0        0 veth4b13dc4c
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 enp2s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     205    0        0 br1
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     204    0        0 br0
```

Here's my netplan file:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
    wlp4s0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
  
  bridges:
    br1:
      interfaces: [enp2s0]
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses: [192.168.1.11/24]
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.1.1
        metric: 1
        on-link: true
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 4
    br0:
      interfaces: [enp3s0]
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
      addresses: [192.168.10.2/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 4
```

I use bridges because I have LXC containers that have bridged interfaces with those two external networks.

I suspect it is the dhclient that keeps adding those routes.

Network Manager is disabled and confirmed it is not running.

I do not use firewall.

This is how I want my routing table to look like:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.2    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 br0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1      0        0 br1
10.0.3.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxcbr0
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     207    0        0 vpn_dom
```

1. How to diagnose the problem? How to disable/reconfigure the process that keeps adding and removing unneeded routes?
2. What to do to get the desired state of the routing table?

---

What kind-of-works is to keep running these 3 commands continuously:

```
watch sudo ip route add 192.168.10.0/24 dev br0
watch sudo route del default gw 192.168.1.1 dev enp2s0
watch sudo route del default gw 192.168.10.2 dev br0
```

Obviously, this constitutes at best a half-working walkaround.

Here are the routes after the fresh reboot produced by the `ip route show`:

````
default via 192.168.1.1 dev br1 proto static metric 1 onlink 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp2s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.11 metric 202 
default via 192.168.10.2 dev br0 proto dhcp src 192.168.10.2 metric 204 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev br1 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.11 metric 205 
10.0.3.0/24 dev lxcbr0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.1 linkdown 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp3s0 scope link src 169.254.220.38 metric 203 
169.254.0.0/16 dev br0 scope link src 169.254.220.38 metric 204 
169.254.0.0/16 dev vpn_dom scope link src 169.254.214.249 metric 207 
169.254.0.0/16 dev veth51ea584b scope link src 169.254.166.248 metric 211 
169.254.0.0/16 dev vethb08250b6 scope link src 169.254.103.110 metric 213 
169.254.0.0/16 dev veth9b43ee1b scope link src 169.254.250.25 metric 215 
169.254.0.0/16 dev veth3ef55092 scope link src 169.254.46.176 metric 217 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp4s0 scope link src 169.254.22.8 metric 306 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.11 metric 202 
192.168.1.0/24 dev br1 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.11 metric 205 
192.168.10.0/24 dev br0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.10.2 metric 204```
````

Comment: What do you mean when you say you suspect it is "the dhclient"? What dhclient? Your netplan config doesn't show any interfaces configured with DHCP, networkd doesn't invoke an external dhclient, and nothing shipping by default in Ubuntu should be doing such a thing.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, @slangasek. I've updated the question.

Comment: The `ip route` output certainly shows that you are getting routes that are tagged dhcp.  but that doesn't correspond to anything in your netplan config.  Do you recall installing dhcp-related software on this system?  What is the output  of `dpkg -l | grep dhcp'?

Answer (score 0):

A first step in diagnosing this would be to check the output of `ip route show` instead of `route` as the former will give you additional clues about the source of the route; e.g. `proto static` vs `proto dhcp`.

It is unlikely to be the result of a DHCP client, since you have routes on all interfaces and routes that should never be sent over / set by DHCP (169.254.0.0).